# How to find whether a web application uses Forms Authentication or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm recently given the task of maintaining a web application. I don't know exactly what form of authentication is being used in the application. I want to confirm whether the application is Forms Authentication. How do I verify this?

Answer (score 2):

Look in the `authentication` section of the `web.config` for the web project:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="logon.aspx" 
           protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

If you have an entry like above, then your web application is using `Forms Authentication`.

Note: The `mode` attribute is what you are interested in, which can have the following values:

- Forms
- Windows
- Passport
- None

Read [authentication Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS version less than 7, checking in the deployed web.config is the only way.

You will need to look for the 
`<authentication> </authentication>` element - specifically the `mode` property.

If you are using IIS 7+, you can also check the settings in the IIS Manager.

Under the `Authentication` category for your web application.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `web.config` file lookf for the `<system.web>` section which will contain an `<authentication>` tag. This tag will be set to `mode="Forms"` for forms auth. You can read over this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on the different authentication methods used in ASP.Net, including `Forms Authenticaiton`.